# Codeigniter form_dropdown mode edit

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is the view when the form in edit mode but if I do not edit that field, in return I get when I want to save it is '#' for column country:

```
<tr class="form-row">
    <td >Country    :   </td>
    <?php 
     if(!empty($ar_countries[$isi->country])) {
       $ar_countries['#'] = $ar_countries[$isi->country]; }
     else{
       $ar_countries['#'] = 'Please Select';
    }
    ?>
    <td class="field">
        <?php echo form_dropdown('country', $ar_countries, '#', 'id="country" name="country"'); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

the value in $ar_countries is like this:

```
array(21) { ["BN"]=> string(17) "Brunei Darussalam" ["KH"]=> string(8) "Cambodia" ["CN"]=> string(5) "China" ["HK"]=> string(21) "Hong Kong (sar) China" ["ID"]=> string(9) "Indonesia" }
```

I save 'BN' as Id_country and 'Brunei Darussalam' as name_country

that dropdown already success to show the selected data but when I re-save it the return change to '#' for column id

example:
I edited Brunei Darussalam without doing anything and saved it what happen after that is the id_country of it change to '#'

What should I do to keep the id as his iso('BN') and not change to '#' ?

Thank you for all suggest and answer really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you always set the selected value to `#` [recall the documentation for that method](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html):

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');
```

The third parameter is the value for the selected option and you set it initially equals to `#` and as you regarded you have not selected any other value so it will be sent to your controller. For edit, change it to be the value saved item as follows:

```
<tr class="form-row">
    <td >Country    :   </td>
    <?php 
     if(!empty($ar_countries[$isi->country])) {
       $val = $ar_countries[$isi->country]; }
     else{
       $val = 'Please Select';
    }
    ?>
    <td class="field">
        <?php echo form_dropdown('country', $ar_countries, $val, 'id="country" name="country"'); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In other words, you have to assured that value of already saved record is selected in the drop-list by any mean.